# JodaTime format error - different formats in different machine

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, jodatime

Im running the following code to generate DateTime

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime("ddMMyyyy");
```

I have a test that takes a string and converts it to Joda DateTime and then tests that value with an expected value.

My test passes on my machine but fails on another machine.

I'm seeing the following error for String `13092019`

```
ime elapsed: 0.189 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
expected:<...ateTime>1970-01-01T0[0]:00:00</common:event...> 
but was:<...ateTime>1970-01-01T0[1]:00:00</common:event...>
```

I just can't seem to understand why and how two different dates are being generated for `13092019`

Comment: Different time zones?

Comment: What is `[0] `and `[1]` in the DateTime. Plus I've got another test doing the same thing but that's passing. Because of this, I don't think it can be to do with different time zones.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. After correcting what I thought was an error in your posted code, I got `2019-09-13T00:00:00.000+02:00`. It neither agrees with the expected nor the actual value you report. [A Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please?

Answer (score 0):

Neither your expected nor your observed result has got any UTC offset. So I’m thinking that you probably want a `LocalDateTime` rather than a `DateTime`. If so, here’s one way to get your expected result, with `00` as hour of day (rather than `01`, as JUnit observed).

```
private static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT = "ddMMyyyy";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
    String text = "13092019";
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDate.parse(text, formatter)
            .toLocalDateTime(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT);
    System.out.println(ldt);
}
```

Output from the program is:

> 2019-09-13T00:00:00.000

`[0]` and `[1]` are just JUnit’s way of highlighting the difference between the two results. Everything before and after `[`…`]` is the same in the expected and the actual value. Neither the expected nor the actual value had any `[` or `]` in it when you ran the test. JUnit added them for emphasis.

> I just can't seem to understand why and how two different dates are
>   being generated for `13092019`

Neither can I without a reproducible example. Scorpioo590 is probably correct that it’s a time zone issue. Most likely you also get different results for other dates. It would seem that the date used in your JUnit run was 1970-01-01 (the epoch day)?